# CRM Data map help

Tags: dynamics-crm

I imported the data from .CSV file and mapped the data with custom attributes. How can I read these mappings from Plugin code? Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

CRM handles the import - creation of the records.  You can register plug-ins on the create message of the entities being imported and look at the entity properties provided to see what was mapped.  See a basic example of plugin examples in the CRM SDK.